# Need to get hierarchy sorted on name at every level

Tags: sql, treeview

We have four columns ID(int),parentID(int),Hierarchy(int),Name in a table. need to get the tree structure for this sorted on name,
for example

the table looks like

```
parentID ID Hierarchy  Name 
NULL     1      1       World
4        3      3       Bombay
1        4      2       Asia
1        6      2       Europe
1        7      2       Australia
7        8      3       Sydney
7        9      3       Melbourne
```

And been able to get this

```
parentID ID Hierarchy  Name 
NULL     1      1       World
1        4      2       Asia
4        3      3       Bombay
1        6      2       Europe
1        7      2       Australia
7        8      3       Sydney
7        9      3       Melbourne
```

want the output like

```
parentID ID Hierarchy  Name 
NULL     1      1       World
1        4      2       Asia
4        3      3       Bombay
1        7      2       Australia
7        9      3       Melbourne
7        8      3       Sydney
1        6      2       Europe
```

was able to sort like 2nd table but got stuck to get them sorted by name maintaining tree structure

my query

```
 ;WITH Level_CTE AS 
(
SELECT 
ParentID, ID, Hierarchy,Name, 0 AS Lvl,CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
FROM Level
WHERE ParentID is null

UNION ALL

SELECT 
O.ParentID, O.ID, O.Hierarchy,O.Name,Lvl + 1 Lvl, CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(o.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
FROM Level O
JOIN Level_CTE zol_CTE
ON O.ParentID = zol_CTE.ID
)

select * into #tempHierarchy from Level_CTE

select * from #tempHierarchy order by Path
```

--Please help here

Answer (score 0):

Hth

```
;WITH Level_CTE AS 
(
SELECT 
ParentID, ID, Hierarchy,Name, 0 AS Lvl,CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
FROM Level
WHERE ParentID is null

UNION ALL

SELECT 
O.ParentID, O.ID, O.Hierarchy,O.Name,Lvl + 1 Lvl, CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(o.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
FROM Level O
JOIN Level_CTE zol_CTE
ON O.ParentID = zol_CTE.ID
)
select * into #tempHierarchy from Level_CTE



select * from #tempHierarchy ORDER BY REPLACE(path,'.','')
```

The Result I am Getting is as below

```
ParentID    ID  Hierarchy   Name    Lvl Path
==============================================
NULL        1   1       World       0   1
1           4   2       Asia        1   1.4
4           3   3       Bombay      2   1.4.3
1           6   2       Europe      1   1.6
1           7   2       Australia   1   1.7
7           8   3       Sydney      2   1.7.8
7           9   3       Melbourne   2   1.7.9
```

Let me know the changes I will reframe it for you.

Thanks

Comment: It is not helping, getting same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it by just replacing id with name in path column. So stupid before!!